# Make a Python function that returns the same arguments as it receives

Tags: python, return, variadic-functions

What is a proper way in Python to write a function that will return the very same parameters it received at run-time?

E.g.:

```
def pass_thru(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something non-destructive with *args & **kwargs
    return ??? <- somehow return *args & **kwargs
```

Comment: return args, kwargs ?

Comment: Show a sample input and expected output

Comment: What, **exactly** is the value you wish to return?

Comment: Note you can pass *multiple* arguments to a function, but a function can only ever return a single value (of course, that value may be a *container* like a tuple...)

Comment: Keyword arguments are not first-class values, so you can't get *exactly* what you pass. `return *args, kwargs` is probably the closest you can get. (That's a single tuple whose first `n` elements are the `n` positional arguments, and the final element is a `dict` constructed from the accumulated keyword arguments.)

Comment: (I.e., `pass_thru(1,2,3,a=4)` can return `(1,2,3,{'a': 4})`, but not `(1, 2, 3, a=4)`)

Comment: If I added 2 prints like this:
```
def pass_thru(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    return ???

pass_thru(pass_thru(1, 2, key='val'))
```
I would like to see the same prints twice:
(1, 2)
{'key': 'value'}

Comment: why do you want to do this? what is your wider aim?

Comment: That you cannot do. You could write `pass_thru(*pass_thru(...))` so that the outer call gets the same positional arguments, but any keyword arguments would be received as a single `dict`, not an unpacked `dict` of key/value pairs.

Comment: @cris_rands
I am playing with functional composition and wanted to write an "if_" higher-order function that will take a predicate and another function. E.g.:
`
def if_(predicate, fn):
    def wrapper(*a, **k):
        if predicate(*a, **k):
            return fn(*a, **k)
        return ???
    return wrapper
`
The goal is to skip the function at run-time if predicate returns False and pass back to the pipeline the same params that were passed to if_. (sorry, don't know how to format code in comments)

Comment: Function composition is not well-defined for Python functions. Mathematically, all function take a single argument and return a single value. Python functions are not mathematical functions. I once tried to enumerate all the ways you might try to define composition of Python functions; I think there were 5 of them. For example, if `g` returns a tuple, do you want composition to be `lambda x: f(g(x))` or `lambda x: f(*g(x))`? Could be either, depending on what `f` expects.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following function:

```
def a(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs
```

When we call the function, the value returned is a tuple, containing first another tuple with the arguments, then a dictionary with the keyword arguments:

```
b = a(1, 2, 3, a='foo')
print(b)
```

Outputs: `((1, 2, 3), {'a': 'foo'})`

```
print(b[0]) # Gives the args as a tuple
print(b[1]) # Gives the kwargs as a dictionary
```

Comment: I am not sure how this can help. Upon return from my function, I would like to leave the stack in the same state as it was when my function was called.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your arguments are just a sequence of values, not a value itself you can manipulate.  Keyword arguments are not themselves first-class values (that is, `a=3` is not a value); they are purely a syntactic construct.

`*` and `**` parameters get you halfway there:

```
def pass_thru(*args, **kwargs):
    return *args, kwargs
```

Then

```
>>> pass_thru(1, 2, a=3)
(1, 2, {'a': 3})
```

but you can't simply pass that back to `pass_thru`; you'll get a different result.

```
>>> pass_thru(pass_thru(1,2,a=3))
((1, 2, {'a': 3}), {})
```

You can try unpacking the tuple:

```
>>> pass_thru(*pass_thru(1,2,a=3))
(1, 2, {'a': 3}, {})
```

but what you really need is to unpack the dict as well. Something like

```
>>> *a, kw = pass_thru(1,2,a=3)
>>> pass_thru(*a, **kw)
(1, 2, {'a': 3})
```

As far as I know, there is no way to combine the last example into a single, nested function call.

Comment: I am on Python 3.6 due to our project constraints. In 3.6 if I use `return *a, **k` IDE complains:
`Python version 3.6 does not support unpacking without parentheses in return statements`

Comment: I never suggested `return *a, **k`: that's a syntax error in any version of Python (at least, through 3.9). `**k` only works in function-call argument lists and dict comprehensions, where there is a known mapping between the key/value pairs and the desired target.

Comment: This is in your example - `return *args, **kwargs`, I just made it shorter.

Comment: No, it is not. `return *args, kwargs` and `return *args, **kwargs` are very different. The former returns a single tuple; the latter is a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! You didn't use `**` before `kwargs`.